# How can I receive temperature messages from an Impinj reader over LLRP?

Tags: c++, llrp

I am attempting to monitor the temperature of a reader over an LLRP connection. In `out_impinj_ltkcpp.h` I see a class called `CImpinjReaderTemperature` that looks mostly boilerplate:

```cpp
class CImpinjReaderTemperature : public CParameter
{
  public:
    CImpinjReaderTemperature (void);
    ~CImpinjReaderTemperature (void);

    static const CFieldDescriptor * const
    s_apFieldDescriptorTable[];

    static const CTypeDescriptor
    s_typeDescriptor;

    //... clipped for brevity
}
```

There is an enumeration that looks useful:

```cpp
enum EImpinjRequestedDataType {
  ImpinjRequestedDataType_All_Configuration = 2000,  /**< All_Configuration */
  ImpinjRequestedDataType_Impinj_Sub_Regulatory_Region = 2001,  /**< Impinj_Sub_Regulatory_Region */
  ImpinjRequestedDataType_Impinj_GPI_Debounce_Configuration = 2003,  /**< Impinj_GPI_Debounce_Configuration */
  ImpinjRequestedDataType_Impinj_Reader_Temperature = 2004,  /**< Impinj_Reader_Temperature */
//...clipped for brevity
}
```

First, how are temperature messages received over LLRP, i.e. do reports need to be requested? Does the temperature need to be polled? Second, how do these parameters fit into LLRP? Which message is the correct one to send (`CGET_READER_CONFIG`, `CUSTOM_MESSAGE`, something else)?

Comment: Does the temperature reader have any useful documentation, like how to read LLRP?

Comment: "Houston, we have a problem."  Which temp sensor are you using, as there are many [temp sensors](https://www.google.com/search?q=llrp+temperature+sensor&rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS935US935&sxsrf=ALiCzsYVuZtU9R-ScseLUX8ENmXi8wAJJA%3A1671050380364&ei=jDSaY9jmFaLjkPIPhvCGqA8&ved=0ahUKEwjY3Mri-_n7AhWiMUQIHQa4AfUQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=llrp+temperature+sensor&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKsCOgoIABBHENYEELADOgcIABCwAxBDOg0ILhDHARDRAxCwAxBDOgQIABBDOgUIABCABDoKCAAQgAQQhwIQFDoGCAAQFhAeOggIABAWEB4QDzoFCAAQhgNKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQkxpYwlRgll1oAXABeACAAbEBiAHuD5IBBDYuMTOYAQCgAQHIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp).

Comment: This is using LLRP to read a temp sensor internal to an RFID reader. The reader I have has something called RShell, and I can send the command `show rfid llrp config` to get the correct temperature. I need to do this through LLRP.

Comment: Does your reader have any LLRP documentation or examples?  Have you tried contacting the mfg of your reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on the LLRP protocol— and especially Impinj extensions— is somewhat lacking or locked behind doors whose keys were lost years ago. That said, I was able to find a document that referenced the Impinj:Temperature message and piece things together from there.

First, the temperature response comes as custom part of a `CGET_READER_CONFIG_RESPONSE` message. This means we need to send a `CGET_READER_CONFIG` message that requests the custom temperature extension:

```cpp
  CGET_READER_CONFIG *pCmd;
  CMessage *pRspMsg;
  CGET_READER_CONFIG_RESPONSE *pRsp;

  // Compose the command message
  pCmd = new CGET_READER_CONFIG();
  pCmd->setRequestedData(GetReaderConfigRequestedData_Identification); // This is cheaper than the default of "all"
  
  CImpinjRequestedData * req = new CImpinjRequestedData();
  req->setRequestedData(ImpinjRequestedDataType_Impinj_Reader_Temperature);
  pCmd->addCustom(req);
```

Attached to that config request message is a `CImpinjRequestData` object that encodes a single integer 2004. This is the significance of the enumeration in my question above. After sending this message, the reader will respond with a response including the identifier we asked for. Without asking for the reader's identification, the value of the requestedData will be 0 which corresponds to "all information" and becomes quite a large message.

Along with the identifier is an `<Impinj:Temperature>` element containing the reader's internal temperature in Celsius. That can be accessed by enumerating the custom field responses (there is only one) and, after checking its type, reading its temperature field:

```cpp
  std::list<CParameter *>::iterator it;
  for (it = pRsp->beginCustom(); it != pRsp->endCustom(); it++ )
  {
    if ((*it)->m_pType == &CImpinjReaderTemperature::s_typeDescriptor)
    {
      CImpinjReaderTemperature* temp = (CImpinjReaderTemperature*) *it;
      if (NULL != temperature_out)
        *temperature_out = temp->getTemperature();
    }
  }
```

While this may not be the most convenient interface to fetch this information, it is working reliably. It can also serve as an example for other fetching other LLRP extensions.